# MegaPixImage Error From FineUploader When Loading Page with RequireJS

Tags: javascript, requirejs, fine-uploader

I am refactoring my application to use RequireJS (using the sbt-web abstraction in Play Framework, but that isn't germane).

First, I simply sought to use a shim to load FineUploader since it isn't AMD-compatible, but I encountered a "*MegaPixImage is not defined*" error. That seemed weird to me since FineUploader has no dependencies (as third-party stuff is built-in).

But after seeing [this Stack Overflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21910531/fineuploader-drawthumbnail-error), I downloaded the [library](https://github.com/stomita/ios-imagefile-megapixel) separately and set up my RequireJS configuration this way (in CoffeeScript):

```
requirejs.config(
  paths:
    megapiximage: './megapiximage'
    fineUploader: './custom.fineuploader'
  shim:
    fineUploader:
      exports: 'fineUploader'
      deps: ['jquery', 'megapiximage' ]
)

require(['./main'], (main) ->
  require(['fineUploader', './myfile'])

  return
)
```

However, I still get the same error even though the library is AMD-compatible.

Any insight into how I should set up my RequireJS configuration is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The FineUploader package references the 'MegaPixImage' variable, so you need to make that available. I think the following should work:

```
require(['fineUploader', 'megapiximage'], function(fineUploader, MegaPixImage) {
    // initialize your fineuploader here
})
```

Note that you have actually included the MegaPixImage library twice now. I therefore decided to keep FineUploader out of my RequireJS setup and add it as a seperate javascript file in the HTML.

Comment: Make sure you do not replace the version of this library bundled with Fine Uploader.  We have heavily modified megapiximage for Fine Uploader, and you can't simply drop in any version of this library to replace the one bundled with Fine Uploader.

Comment: In fact, newer versions of Fine Uploader namespace megapiximage.

Comment: @Bjorn, can you show how you added FineUploader as a separate file? When I add it with a simple script tag either before or after my RequireJS markup, I get a "*jQuery is not defined*" at line 13206 of `fineuploader.js`. Did you simply not use the [JQuery plugin](http://docs.fineuploader.com/integrating/jquery.html) in FineUploader?

Comment: Correct, I use FineUploader Basic. You could also copy the MegaPixImage version from FineUploader to a seperate file and then use that for the answer provided here. Not so pretty, but it should work...